# Manipulating Asymptotic Catalan Expansions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, asymptotics, catalan-numbers

I need help explaining the steps below pulled from a proof.

*Solution*:

Stirlings Formula: $N! = \sqrt{2\pi N}(\frac N e)^N(1+\frac {1}{12N} + \frac{1}{288N^2}- \frac{139}{51840N^3}+O(\frac{1}{N^4})$

Catalan Numbers: $\frac{1}{N+1} {2N \choose N}$

**After substituting $N!$ into Catalan numbers and simplifying, I am stumped on how the following steps are obtained and evaluated:**

(Step 1:)

$ = (\frac{1}{N+1})(\frac{4^N}{\sqrt{ N \pi }})(\frac{1+\frac{1}{24N}+\frac{1}{288(4N^2)}-\frac{139}{51840(8N^3)}+O(\frac{1}{N^4})}{1+\frac{1}{6N}+\frac{1}{72N^2}-\frac{31}{6480N^3}+O(\frac{1}{N^4})} $

(Step 2:)

$= (\frac{1}{N(1+\frac 1 N)})(\frac{4^N}{\sqrt{ N \pi }})({1+\frac{1}{24N}+\frac{1}{288(4N^2)}-\frac{139}{51840(8N^3)}+O(\frac{1}{N^4})})*(1-(\frac{1}{6N}+\frac{1}{72N^2}-\frac{31}{6480N^3}+O(\frac{1}{N^4}))+(\frac{1}{6N}+\frac{1}{72N^2}-\frac{31}{6480N^3}+O(\frac{1}{N^4}))^2-(\frac{1}{6N}+\frac{1}{72N^2}-\frac{31}{6480N^3}+O(\frac{1}{N^4}))^3+O(\frac{1}{N^4})) $

(Step 3:)

$= \frac{4^N}{N(1+\frac 1 N)\sqrt{ \pi N }} (1 - \frac{1}{8N} + \frac{1}{128N^2} + \frac{5}{1024N^3}+ O(\frac{1}{N^4}))$

(Step 4:)

$ = \frac{4^N}{\sqrt{\pi N}} (1 - \frac{1}{8N} + \frac{1}{128N^2} + \frac{5}{1024N^3}+ O(\frac{1}{N^4}))(1-\frac{1}{N}+\frac{1}{N^2}-\frac{1}{N^3}+O(\frac{1}{N^4})) $

I am confused about how the author went from steps 2-4. Could anyone explain, please? I know it's algebra, but having trouble with it and tell me where $\frac{1}{1-x}= 1+x+x^2+x^3+O(x^4) $ fits into these steps?

Comment: Please check your missing parentheses and use two dollar symbols before and after your formula to produce a displayed equation instead of an inline one. You use $$
\frac{1}{{1 + x}} = 1 - x + x^2  - x^3  + O(x^4 )
$$ with $$
x = \frac{1}{{6N}} + \frac{1}{{72N^2 }} - \frac{{31}}{{6480N^3 }} + O\!\left( {\frac{1}{{N^4 }}} \right).
$$

Answer (score 2):

$$C_n=\frac 1{n+1}\binom{2 n}{n}=\frac 1{n+1}\frac{(2 n)!}{(n!)^2}=\frac{(2 n)!}{n! (n+1)!}$$ Now, you could make life simpler writing
$$\log(C_n)=\log[(2n)!]-\log[n!]-\log[(n+1)!]$$ Using Stirling three times and continuing with Taylor series to get
$$\log(C_n)=n \log (4)-\frac{1}{2} \log \left({\pi  n^3}\right)-\frac{9}{8 n}+\frac{1}{2
   n^2}-\frac{21}{64 n^3}+\frac{1}{4 n^4}-\frac{129}{640 n^5}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^6}\right)$$
Now, using
$$C_n=e^{\log(C_n)}=\frac {4^n}{n\sqrt{\pi n}}\left(1-\frac{9}{8 n}+\frac{145}{128 n^2}-\frac{1155}{1024 n^3}+\frac{36939}{32768
   n^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)\right)$$

Comment: Would this also work if Stirling's formula is: $ln(N!) = (N+\frac{1}{2})ln(N)-N+ln\sqrt{2 \pi} + \frac{1}{12N}-\frac{1}{360N^3} + O(\frac{1}{N^4})$? I am assuming just replace this with my original formula and I should get my desired answer after simplifying?

Comment: If you use it, you would obtain  the same $$\log(C_n)=n \log (4)-\frac{1}{2} \log \left({\pi  n^3}\right)-\frac{9}{8 n}+\frac{1}{2
   n^2}-\frac{21}{64 n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$ $$C_n=\frac {4^n}{n\sqrt{\pi n}}\left(1-\frac{9}{8 n}+\frac{145}{128 n^2}-\frac{1155}{1024 n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)\right)$$

Comment: Could you explain how you used the Stirling and Taylor Series to get $C_n$?

Comment: @gfgd. When you use Stirling formula for $\log(p!)$ and you want  the asymptotics of $\log[(n+1)!]$ you make $p=n+1$ in the formula and in order to have only terms in powers of $n$, you need to use Taylor for each of them. Is it clear ? Cheers